# С++ Быстрое чтение из текстового файла

Tags: c++

Осваиваю с++ после c#.
Пишу программу для обработки словарей для на с++.

Хочу считывать файл в память в виде массива строк или вектора со строками

столкнулся с проблемой выбора варианта считывания текстового файла с диска. Диск SSD.
файл размером 136 МБ считывается вот таким способом:

```
ifstream file("rockyou.txt");

file.seekg(0, ios_base::end);

size_t size = file.tellg();

file.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);

string buffer(size, ' ');

file.read(&buffer[0], size);
```

за ~700 мс. Быстро, но в буфере получаем массив символов и для построчной дальнейшей обработки это не подходит.
Если считывать так:

```
   list<string> stringList;

   if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (!file.eof())
        {
            getline(file, line);
            stringList.push_back(line);
        }
        file.close();
    }
```

То считывается в лист строк за 7800 мс. Обрабатывать строки можно, но скорость низкая.
К примеру C# в таком варианте даже с проверкой на условие тот же словарь обрабатывает за 1380мс:

```
 using(StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(inputDict))
    {
        string s = String.Empty;
        while ((s = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            
            if(s.Length>7 && s.Length < 30 && !(s.IndexOf(' ') >= 0))
            {
                count++; 
            }
        }    
        
    }
```

Хочется именно разобраться с решением задачи в среде С++ больше с образовательной целью.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7868936/13970074

Comment: А почему не считывать файл в буффер, а уже потом разбивать содержимое так как вам угодно? Вы же все равно весь файл считываете

Comment: вот эта строка `string buffer(size, ' ');` кушает много много. Ей ведь не только нужно память выделить, а и заполнить ее данными, которые будут очень скоро перетерты.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Как потом массив символов перевести в массив строк, это же займёт какое-то время. Может есть вариант быстрого чтения в массив строк например?

Comment: @KoVadim Есть ли вариант избежать этих потерь?

Comment: @Deim чем вас не устраивают решения по ссылке?

Comment: @dIm0n сейчас как раз пытаюсь повторить вариант на С

Comment: @Deim ок, можете дать ответ на собственный вопрос ниже (не в вопросе), когда разберётесь

Comment: Скиньте пример словаря, у меня есть идея на си, но... увы без данных я бессилен.

Comment: @ヒミコ  https://github.com/brannondorsey/naive-hashcat/releases/download/data/rockyou.txt

Comment: @Deim - либо выделять неинициализированную память  (через malloc), либо сделать чтения большими блоками (по 8-16кб) и парсингом. Вряд ли вся строка нужна в памяти сразу. Ещё один вариант, который я когда то делал - это считать эту строку, но паралельно держать вектор индексов, где какая строка начинается. Таким образом можно избежать лишнего копирования

Comment: @Deim так вы в любом случае конвертите массив символов в массив строк. При этом делать это при чтении, априори, будет медленне, чем с уже считанным файлом (просто из-за количества вызовов)

Comment: А чем не угодил ваш первый вариант stream::read() ? Если я ничего не путаю, то в буфер копируется блок данных без изменений, т.е. вы получаете строки, разделённые '\n', просто все подряд, в одном буфере. С ними вполне можно работать после этого.

Comment: Как выше подметили, нет смысла зполнять буфер чем-либо заранее. Можно использовать `std::vector`, он создаётся пустой. Затем вызываем на нём
`vector::reserve(size_type n);`
Чтобы занять сразу нужный объём памяти. Это намного быстрее, чем создавать строку пробелов длиной в мегабайт.

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее быстрый способ открытия файла оказался следующим (~300мс):

```
std::ifstream infile;
infile.open("D:\\dict\\rockyou.txt", std::ios::binary); // откроем файл как бинарный
infile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
size_t file_size_in_byte = infile.tellg();
std::vector<char> data; // будем использовать для хранения текста
data.resize(file_size_in_byte);
infile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
infile.read(&data[0], file_size_in_byte);

string test(data.begin(), data.end()); //переведём в одну строку
```

Как упоминали в комментариях выше в полученной строке все строки из исходного файла разделены '\n'. Пока не нашёл способ закинуть все слова в массив или вектор. При попытке в цикле запихнуть слова в вектор получаю что объем памяти увеличивается до 2 и более Гб. При весе исходного файла в 136 мб.

```
string tmp;
vector<string> stringList;
for (char ch : data)
{
    if (ch != '\n')
    {
        tmp += ch;
    }
    else
    {            
        stringList.push_back(tmp);            
        tmp.clear();            
    }
}
```

Comment: В последнем коде память под строку многократно перевыделяется. Вместо этого можно при нахождении `\n` создать строку нужной длины и скопировать в неё данные от прошлого `\n`

Comment: @MBo а можете поподробней написать, в каком месте память перевыделяется? и как этого избежать.

Comment: думаю, даже код выше можно сильно ускорить. Там одно лишнее копирование

Comment: память перевыделяется вот здесь: `tmp += ch;` На каждый символ происходит обновление строки, т.е. ~136 миллионов раз.

Comment: @MBo К сожалению не понимаю как этого избежать. Мы пробегаемся по всем символам в векторе. То есть нам все равно нужно где-то хранить символы от \n до \n. То есть с самого начала алгоритм смотрит на символ, и он не равен \n. значит нужно его куда-то положить. далее тоже самое и потом когда наконец пришёл символ \n нужно полученное значение положить в вектор. заранее мы не знаем длинну строки между переносами. Она может быть 4 символа или 254 символа.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что в сумме с кодом формирования вектора строк, версия с `getline` в итоге окажется быстрее.

Comment: Нужно помнить только позицию - ведь всё остальное уже хранится в векторе data. Сделал ответом псевдокод, т.к. в комментах неудобно писать.

Comment: Мои "5 копеек" ... Текстовые файлы могут иметь разные терминаторы строк: win - `0D0A`, *nix - `0A`, osX - `0D`, и это нужно учитывать. Второе. Для ускорения файловых операций посредством `std::ifstream` - желательно ему выделить побольше буфер (например 1-2 мега, нужно экспериментировать) с помощью `streambuf* rdbuf (streambuf* sb)`. Ну и в третьих, для `std::vector` резервировать место "пачками" через каждые N итераций (пусть N = 2048). Когда-то тестил подобное, данные "советы" достаточно неплохо приблизили быстродействие с сырому буферизированному чтению.

Answer (score 0):

Псевдокод для разбора массива данных по строкам (на случай, если стандартные методы с cin и пр. не хочется применять):

```
string tmp;
int returnpos = 0;
vector<string> stringList;
for (int i = 0; i< datalength; i++)
{
    if (data[i] == '\n')
    {
        make string tmp with length = i - returnpos
        movememory(&data[returnpos + 1], &tmp[0], i - returnpos);
        stringList.push_back(tmp);            
        returnpos = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё равно что-то не то. Не пойму. проблема с памятью возникает после добавления строки в вектор. Выглядит это как увеличение объёма занимаемой памяти до 2-х Гб и потом вылет с ошибкой. В принципе в прошлых вариантах было тоже самое. Откуда там 2 Гб?